# Finding patterns in a numerical signal

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Let's consider some 2D signals (amplitude over time).

I have a library of snippets that have specific 'shapes'. For the sake of the example, let's assume a square wave, a triangle wave and a sawtooth wave, but in practice, they're a lot more complex.

And I have a complex signal, such as an audio recording.

What would be the best way to train a system to spot elements from the library inside the complex signal, knowing that:

- The library shape may be present at a different frequency.
- The library shape may be present at a different amplitude.
- Multiple shapes can be overlapping.
- There is noise all over.

What I would like to recover is:

- Which shape was recognized.
- How close is it to the reference signal.
- Where does that shape fit in the complex signal (position, frequency, amplitude range).
- Bonus problem: since I'm looking for the shape itself, it may be stretched over time in a non linear fashion.

I draw a quick picture to illustrate:

[image]

As an example here, I drew 3 basic shapes for my library and I overlapped a few at different places on an audio signal.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

I would lean toward training a classifier to recognize the shapes, but I am not sure this is the right approach, nor really how practical it would be with this kind of data which has frequencies well distributed all across a wide range (50hz to 15khz).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a labeled data set, I would probably try a simplified convolutional autoencoder.

If the base shapes that you want to recognize are fixed, I would use 
a single hidden layer (the bottleneck) where the kernel functions are set to base shapes. The values of the neurons at the bottleneck would tell you which shapes are detected and where.

Comment: how would this handle when a shape is stretched (over time), but possible at a different shape through the shape?

Comment: You could have different filters with different stretching factors if a finite number of different stretching would suffice. Your problems start to look more and more like a wavelet analysis. Maybe your problem is simpler if you do first a wavelet analysis.